# Bootstrap4 with wide table and horizontal scroll bar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I use bootstrap4 to build the table. But I hope the table can:

1. When the columns too many, have the horizontal scroll bar even on the desktop screen
2. columns will not auto full fill the container

Just like the following:

[image]

[image]

Is it possible doing that by using bootstrap? Thanks.

Comment: You can check here https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b4/jquery/tables/scroll/ may be this can help you.

Comment: think about datatable https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/state_saving